# How to count equal values of the same element name [xQuery]

Tags: xquery

Here is an example:

`

```
<bracketQualifier>
   <bracketSequenceNumber>1</bracketSequenceNumber>
</bracketQualifier>
<bracketQualifier>
   <bracketSequenceNumber>1</bracketSequenceNumber>
</bracketQualifier>
<bracketQualifier>
   <bracketSequenceNumber>1</bracketSequenceNumber>
</bracketQualifier>
```

`
What i need to do is if bracketSequenceNumber holds the same value trow an exception.
Number of elements is N there can be more than 3. How can i achieve this using xquery.

I tried something like this without success and i cant say i understand xQuery completley:

`

```
let $count := ( for  $bracketSequenceNumber in $bracketQualifier/bracketSequenceNumber return count(bracketQualifier[@bracketSequenceNumber = $bracketSequenceNumber ])) return
if($GDSN_PriceSyncPriceSegmentTM/value ='250' and $count >= 1) then something
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if (count(//bracketSequenceNumber) 
    != count(distinct-values(//bracketSequenceNumber) then ...
```

If you actually want to find the duplicates, use `group by` in XQuery 3.1 to process each group of equal values and test whether the group size is 2 or more.